# Is there an obligation to reattach a severed body part?

Tags: halacha, medicine, parts-of-the-body

If a part of a person's body is severed for whatever reason, is there an obligation on the person who lost it to reattach it?

Comment: @Shokhet and co. i've edited it

Comment: I am having trouble imagining a situation where he wouldn't want to, if he could.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @MonicaCellio The reattachment surgery may result in decreased movement or ability, especially compared to a high tech prosthetic.  (I don't know how common that is, but it isn't impossible)

Comment: I would say not. Just like there is no mitzvah to be michayei meisim, there is no mitzvah to bring this limb back to life.

Comment: I've never woven my hair back in. Or attached fingernails. Fwiw. (Otoh, I *have* [had my blood put back in my body](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateletpheresis).)

Comment: Why do you think there might be?